# Representation for the Bose-Mesner algebra and its dual.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, representation-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

If you are familiar with the algebra, just skip the following brief introduction, that is fine.

> In the study of [Bose-Mesner algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Mesner_algebra). We know given that the commutative association scheme $\mathfrak{X}:=(X,\{R_{i}\}_{0\leq i\leq d}).$ Its Bose-Mesner algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ has two natural basis, that is, the adjacency matrices $A_{0},A_{1},...,A_{d}$ and the idempotent matrices $E_{0},E_{1},...,E_{d}.$ In the latter case, we denote $\mathfrak{A}^{\circ}$ instead of $\mathfrak{A}$ since it is the algebra with respect to the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). For fix $0\leq i\leq d,$ we have
> \begin{align}
> A_{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{d}P_{i}(j)E_{j}\quad\text{and}\quad E_{i}=\frac{1}{|X|}\sum_{j=0}^{d}Q_{i}(j)A_{j}
> \end{align}
> These two base change matrices $P=(P_{j}(i))_{0\leq i,j\leq d}$ and $Q=(Q_{j}(i))_{0\leq i,j\leq d}$ are called the *first eigenmatrix* and the *second eigenmatrix*, respectively.
> On the other hand, from the representation theory, there are *left regular representations* $\rho:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow M_{d+1}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\rho^{*}:\mathfrak{A}^{\circ}\rightarrow M_{d+1}(\mathbb{C}).$ Moreover, they are isomorphisms of algebras $\rho:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}\subset M_{d+1}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\rho^{*}:\mathfrak{A}^{\circ}\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}^{*}\subset M_{d+1}(\mathbb{C}),$ where $M_{d+1}(\mathbb{C})$ is the full matrix algebra of degree $d+1$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ is so called [Intersection Algebra](https://d-nb.info/972889272/34) and $\mathfrak{B}^{*}$ as its dual.

Sorry for long introduction, now, I just think about two questions as follows.

**Q1: Are the representations $\rho$ and $\rho^{*}$ similar ?** That is, does there exist a non-singular matrix $U$ such that $\rho=U\rho^{*}U^{-1}.$ I think the answer should be positive, but I am not very sure.

**Q2: Do we have a natural morphism or map from $\mathfrak{B}$ to $\mathfrak{B}^{*}$? If so, is this a commutative diagram ?** In the picture, we have

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathfrak{A} @>{\rho:A_{i}\mapsto}B_{i}>> \mathfrak{B}\\
@V P VV  \\
\mathfrak{A}^{\circ} @>{\rho^{*}:|X|E_{i}\mapsto}B_{i}^{*}>> \mathfrak{B}^{*}
\end{CD}

where $\mathfrak{B}=\langle B_{0},B_{1}...,B_{d}\rangle$ and $\mathfrak{B}^{*}=\langle B_{0}^{*},B_{1}^{*}...,B_{d}^{*}\rangle.$

Any comment or advice I will be grateful. Thanks for patient reading.